# How to merge rows in R?

Tags: r, merge, tidy

I have a data like this:

```
 name    A_1 B_1 A_2 B_2
"Jack"    20  NA  15  NA
"Jack"    NA  12  NA  30
"James"   22  NA  14  NA
"James"   NA  32  NA  20
```

I want to merge the rows like this:

```
name    A_1 B_1 A_2 B_2
"Jack"  20  12  15  30
"James" 22  32  14  20
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we group by the name, next fill all other columns that have missing data, first down, then up and last take the unique records.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(name) %>% 
  fill(everything(), .direction = "downup") %>% 
  distinct()

# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   name [2]
  name    A_1   B_1   A_2   B_2
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Jack     20    12    15    30
2 James    22    32    14    20
```

Comment: Can we put specific columns in fill?

Comment: @Mina, you could use something like `fill(starts_with(c("A", "B")), .direction = "downup")` which selects the columns starting with A or B. Of course, depending on the rest of the columns, the distinct might not work. Check the help with `starts_with` for other selection mechanisms